# sparql getting all months between two dates SPARQL

Tags: date, sparql

I am working on a **SPARQL query** in TopBraid Composer  to get the number of data quality rules in each month.

I have a Start Date and End Date, but **I need to get all the months between the start date and end date so that I can get a count of the data quality rules applicable to that duration.**

My current query and result is as follows-:

```
SELECT *    
WHERE    
{    
   ?Rules CDE:Data_Quality_Rule_added_on ?Date1.    
   ?Rules CDE:Data_Quality_Removed_On ?Date2

   BIND(month(?Date1) AS ?Month1)    
   BIND(month(?Date2) AS ?Month2)    
   BIND(smf:duration("mon",?Date1,?Date2) AS ?dur)    
}    
LIMIT 5

| [Rules]                  | Date1      | Date2      | Month1 | Month2 | dur    
| CDE:Data_Quality_Rule_13 | 2016-01-28 | 2016-09-15 | 01     | 09     | 8   
| CDE:Data_Quality_Rule_16 | 2016-02-29 | 2016-08-08 | 02     | 08     | 5   
| CDE:Data_Quality_Rule_18 | 2016-05-15 | 2016-10-31 | 05     | 10     | 6   
| CDE:Data_Quality_Rule_4  | 2016-03-28 | 2016-07-02 | 03     | 07     | 3   
| CDE:Data_Quality_Rule_5  | 2016-02-02 | 2016-06-06 | 02     | 06     | 4
```

I am able to get the start month,end month and the duration. But I would like to get all the months between the start month and end month in SPARQL. The end result is to get the month-wise count of the number of data qulaity rules based on the start and end date as follows-:

```
| Months   | Number Of Data Quality Rules |
|  1       | 2                        
|  2       | 4                            
|  3       | 6                            
|  4       | 3                             
|  5       | 3                            
|  6       | 4                           
|  7       | 4                            
|  8       | 4                            
|  9       | 5                             
|  10      | 3                             
|  11      | 2                             
|  12      | 5
```

Comment: This is an interesting question. :)

Comment: Did lot of research...didn't find an answer any where. Thank you so much for you time and help!!

Comment: I think the key to solving some of these kinds of problems is recognizing that many query languages don't let you generate data, so you have to provide it explicitly and "join" on it. In this case, we're providing a list of the legal values of ?month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, some data to work with that has some rules with begin and end dates:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

:rule1 :begin "2011-01-10T14:45:13.815-05:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
       :end   "2011-06-10T14:45:13.815-05:00"^^xsd:dateTime .

:rule2 :begin "2011-04-10T14:45:13.815-05:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
       :end   "2011-10-10T14:45:13.815-05:00"^^xsd:dateTime .

:rule3 :begin "2011-06-10T14:45:13.815-05:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
       :end   "2011-11-10T14:45:13.815-05:00"^^xsd:dateTime .
```

Then you can write a query that gets the months in which each rule is active.  IF you then group by the month, and count the number of rules, you get the number of rules active in each month:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select ?rule ?month {
  #-- Specify the possible values for ?month
  #-- in advance.  These are just the numbers
  #-- one through twelve.
  values ?month { 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 }

  #-- Get the begin and end dates of that
  #-- you're interested in.  The way you
  #-- do this depends on the structure of
  #-- your data, of course.
  ?rule :begin ?begin ; :end ?end .

  #-- Then take only the values of ?month
  #-- that are between the beginning month
  #-- and the ending month.
  filter ( month(?begin) <= ?month && ?month <= month(?end) )
}
```

```
------------------
| rule   | month |
==================
| :rule1 | 1     |
| :rule1 | 2     |
| :rule1 | 3     |
| :rule1 | 4     |
| :rule1 | 5     |
| :rule1 | 6     |
| :rule2 | 4     |
| :rule2 | 5     |
| :rule2 | 6     |
| :rule2 | 7     |
| :rule2 | 8     |
| :rule2 | 9     |
| :rule2 | 10    |
| :rule3 | 6     |
| :rule3 | 7     |
| :rule3 | 8     |
| :rule3 | 9     |
| :rule3 | 10    |
| :rule3 | 11    |
------------------
```

Now you can group those results by month, and then count the number of rules for each month:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select ?month (count(distinct ?rule) as ?numRules) where {
  values ?month { 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 }

  ?rule :begin ?begin ; :end ?end .

  filter ( month(?begin) <= ?month && ?month <= month(?end) )
}
group by ?month
```

```
--------------------
| month | numRules |
====================
| 1     | 1        |
| 2     | 1        |
| 3     | 1        |
| 4     | 2        |
| 5     | 2        |
| 6     | 3        |
| 7     | 2        |
| 8     | 2        |
| 9     | 2        |
| 10    | 2        |
| 11    | 1        |
--------------------
```

That doesn't include month 12 in the result, because there were no rules active then.  If you want all the months to be listed, you can make the rule matching part optional:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select ?month (count(distinct ?rule) as ?numRules) {
  values ?month { 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 }

  optional {
    ?rule :begin ?begin ; :end ?end .
    filter ( month(?begin) <= ?month && ?month <= month(?end) )
  }
}
group by ?month
```

```
--------------------
| month | numRules |
====================
| 1     | 1        |
| 2     | 1        |
| 3     | 1        |
| 4     | 2        |
| 5     | 2        |
| 6     | 3        |
| 7     | 2        |
| 8     | 2        |
| 9     | 2        |
| 10    | 2        |
| 11    | 1        |
| 12    | 0        |
--------------------
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua...it worked!!! Was trying to solve this issue since yday!!! U rock!!